# is an unnamed semaphore (via sem_init) pure user space?

Tags: linux, semaphore

On Linux (2.6.27),  when I call sem_init() to init an unnamed semaphore in shared memory,  is this semaphore pure user space, or controlled by the Linux kernel?

If the process that holding this semaphore dies, will the semaphore be released automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in the userspace, and if the process kills, the semaphore is released from its memory, but the value of the semaphore is retained as it is in shared memory